# From Java code in eclipse to UML class diagrams in Omnigraffle

Tags: java, uml

Is there a way to get reversed engineered uml diagrams into Omnigraffle?
I got a bunch of eclipse plugins that can create UML class diagrams, but not in a format that Omnigraffle can handle.
Is there any way to get my project from eclipse to Omnigraflle?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is strange but no XMI export to Omnigraffe is available from UML 2.3.

I don't think this is a big job to be done so you can do it by yourself. You need to take the EclipseUML2 metamodel or the EMF model then manually identify each model element (e.g a class in UML 2.3 is .....in Omnigraffe, etc....)
Once all the elements have been identify then code a xml mapper. It would work.
A good mapper is about 18 months work for one engineer, but if you are 5 of you you can do it in less than 3-6 months (2months for codding and 4 months for testing).
Good luck for this potential project.

My question could be why the Omni Group has not done the xml export ?

Answer (score 5):

I've created a little plugin for Eclipse in order to create an OmniGraffle UML-like class diagram from a Java package. It does not create files, but instead uses AppleScript to direcly draw the diagram in an opened OmniGraffle drawing. The plugin provides some options in order to control the diagram creation, e.g., show or hide private attributes etc. Parameterized collections are transformed into associations, however there is room for improvement. The plugin is described at
     http://jpilgrim.github.com/eclipsetools/j2og/
where you will also find a link to the update site in order to easily install the plugin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.